Voltage regulator with polarity depending on input
I'm pretty new to electronics, I have some very basic notions, and I need help with a little project I'm working on, basically I have an input that can vary between 4 and 13 volts and I need to keep a voltage that is fixed at around 1.4 volts, the catch is that the polarity of the input voltage can be inverted, and the output voltage should reflect the polarity of the input.
In other words I need to have the same polarity on the output but with a fixed voltage.
I found out on Wikipedia that a very simple voltage regulator can be constructed with a transistor, a resistor and a zener diode, but it only works with a fixed polarity, so I tried (with my very limited knowledge) to draw a schematic that would do what I need but I'm not sure at all that it can work, so I'm asking help to anyone with more experience than me.
On the left there's the input, and on the right is the output.

EDIT:
The load are some leds that each draw around 20mA, these leds have only 2 pins, and switching the polarity of those pins basically changes the color of the led, that's why I need to have the same polarity of the input.
I need a constant tension to have a constant luminosity from those leds regardless of the input voltage (i found out by trial and error that around 1.4 volts across the pins of the led give a good luminosity so that is the target voltage).
I already tried to just put a 2k Ohm resistor on one of the pins of those leds, but the luminosity of the led changes drastically between 1.4 and 3 volts, so I can't actually just put a resistor there.
EDIT 2:
Supposing the used led has 2 pins, pin_1 and pin_2



pin_1
pin_2
led color




+
-
white


-
+
red



The desired truth table of the supposed voltage regulator is as follows:



input pin 1
input pin 2
output pin 1
output pin 2




+
-
+
-


-
+
-
+



Note that the output pins are those which are regulated to these supposed 1.4 volts
Thanks in advance to anyone.

What is the 1.4V load? How much current it requires? Why it needs same polarity as input?

The load is 4 LEDs of 20 mA each. It needs the same polarity as the input because I got some LEDs that change color depending on the polarity

Are the load simply LEDs, or LEDs and something else? Because this sounds like you actually don't need or want to send fixed 1.4V to LEDs, if you simply want to light up LEDs. Also what is the supply source, does it just try to light up LEDs with different colors?

I need a constant voltage to keep the led at a constant brightness, the load are just LEDs, nothing else, is to keep them at a fixed luminosity regardless of the input voltage

Usually you need constant current for the LEDs, not constant voltage. Unless you know something about the LEDs, like do they already have a resistor in series?

I know very little about these LEDs, just that if you change polarity they change color. Also I've no idea how to keep the current constant. I mean the desider final output should be that regardless of voltage the led should stay at a constant luminosity

So, if I am reading this correctly: when the input voltage is POSITIVE and between 4 and 13V, the LEDs in one string (call this string A) shall be illuminated.  And when the input voltage is NEGATIVE and between 4 & 13V, then the LEDs in a different string (call this string B) shall be illuminated.  Is that basically what you need?

Sort of, the led is one, it has only 2 pins, like a normal led, the only difference is that if you put the voltage in reverse the led instead of being white will be red

Sounds XY problem. Can you make a truth table or graph of how the LEDs should light up according to input? Gradual or on/off? Ignore drive voltages, just input and visible output.

Sure, I'll add it in the original question to make it more clear

Here is one way to get a constant birectional current. This is just two constant current limiter circuits in inverse series with Schottky diodes to bypass the one not being used.
You can adjust R2 and R4 to individually adjust the currents through D2/D3 LEDs.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
However- you might want to try it with just a series resistor of, say, 1kΩ before mucking with all that complexity.
The apparent brightness won't change all that much with voltage (and the resulting changing current) due to the way human eyes work.

Thank you! I already tried just putting before it a 2k ohm resistor. But the brightness still changes drastically with voltage, with just 3 volts it is surprisingly bright, I mean the change from 1.4 to 3 volts has a drastic change in luminosity. Note that the voltage is not alternating in a normal way (like the voltage on the house line for example), it changes polarity con command (with a button), so it isn't oscillating regularly, it is still DC.

My comment with refers to voltage changes over the +/-  4-13V range you mentioned. Below +/-4V brightness decrease rapidly, depending on the actual LED characteristics.

Red LEDs typically require about 1.8 volts to light, while white LEDs require 3 volts - I don't think 1.4 volts will light your LEDs in either polarity.

The LEDs can handle a maximum of 3 volts, I've tried and with 1.4 volts (measured across the led pins, after the 2k ohm resistance) they achieve an acceptable and desidred luminosity.

You can try this:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
You're going to have to screw around with the resistors to trade off power dissipation for luminous uniformity. Another easy approach would to use JFETs:

simulate this circuit
This is probably the bare minimum that works given your requirements. You can tweak the current by adding resistor(s) between the gate and source of the JFET(s)

Here is a solution which is a variation of Spehro Pefhany's

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
It uses a diode bridge to rectify the voltage applied to a current regulator circuit. The drawback (or advantage) of this circuit is that the current will be the same in both directions. Sometimes you might want that. However, if you have different colored LEDs, you may not, because the different colored LEDs may have different apparent luminosities for the same current. (luminosity may not be the correct term for the subjective experience of "brightness").

I don't have a clue regarding the last part, but by trying with a 2k ohm resistor I noticed that the brightness (what I saw, to be clear) was the same and the one I wanted, so I think that a constant current and voltage may be a good thing (?)

If it works, great! I have read that some people find blue LEDs much brighter than red for the same current. So, it some cases one might want to have different currents for the different LEDs.
